# primefaces with custom css file

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, commandbutton

Good morning, i have a problem in applying a style sheet on a primefaces `commandButton` , the button element is as follows:

```
        <p:commandButton value="Complains" styleClass="styleOrange"/>
```

and the style sheet:

```
    .styleOrange {    
    background-color: orange;
}
```

the css file is placed in the resources folder under css folder:

here's the include statement of the css file:

```
<h:head>

<h:outputStylesheet name="/resources/css/style.css" library="css" />

</h:head>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no need for the `/resources/` prefix. JSF already implicitly loads resources from there.

Just change the name into `css/style.css`, like this:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
```

---

You should also read this [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Answer (score -1):

U must edit path of css file:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="#{request.contextPath}/css/style.css"/>
```

Comment: Two things wrong here: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used 2) the contextPath is included by the component.